# Detecting when a page has finished loading in a Firefox plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm writing a Firefox extension and as part of this extension I need to know when the page has fully loaded (including all images and flash etc). Does anyone know of an event that is triggered when the page has fully loaded? I'm thinking it would be the same event that controls the activity icon in the top right. If anyone knows what event that is it would be very helpful.

Comment: If you have any JavaScript on the page that writes content using Ajax then you will miss that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
getBrowser().addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think they are using `nsIWebProgressListener` there and its `onStateChange` event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWebProgressListener

Comment: I've tried this. In my onStateChange method in the listener I have

        if (aFlag & Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_WINDOW &&
            aFlag & Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP)
        {
            //do my stuff here
        }

but I still see some flash objects loaded after this happens. I need to know when there are no more requests in progess. Any ideas?